# Android: Facebook login cannot call the selection fragment (Facebook api 3.0)

Tags: android, facebook

I  followed the tutorial of Facebook to create a login function with Facebook (
[enter link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/#step2)). When running the example, I had problem: after authorizing the app, I cannot see the welcome Text (selection fragment), it just went back the login page(splash fragment). 
As my debug, the Session of Facebook seems not to be opened. Please give me some advices. Thanks

Comment: Any error messages would be helpful. Or print out the exception that comes when your session transitions to the closed state. Another possibility is that you're not overriding the onActivityResult method in your activity or fragment, which means the SDK doesn't get the result from the SSO operation.

Comment: Actually, it authenticated, and just loaded again the splash fragment, no error. As debugging, the session state: Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:############. For that reason, app cannot load the selection fragment. Any idea?

Comment: Are you able to run and log in with any of the samples that came bundled with the SDK, ex: HelloFacebookSample?

Comment: I can run all the samples of Facebook, however, I cannot create a login function by myseft although I followed step by step as Facebook Dev guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're providing the correct Key Hash.
Take your key with this method:

```
static final String GetKey(Context context)
{
    String KeyHash = "";
    PackageInfo info;
    try {
        info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),  PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            KeyHash = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        }

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return KeyHash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was because I was not overriding the onActivityResult method, after I implemented that everything worked.  Since it seems that your session is failing authentication have you updated your applicationId in the manifest?  I'm not sure it really matters but there is also a section on the facebook app settings page that requires the name of your activity, make sure that matches your current app.